# Float vs double Math Java

Tags: java, floating-point, precision

Is there a precision difference between the following (assuming the value of a and b can be represented without loss of precision in a float).

With floats:

```
float a;
float b;
double result = 1 + a*b;
```

With doubles:

```
double a;
double b;
double result = 1 + a*b;
```

Comment: There is by definition; a `float` is a 32bit, base 2 IEEE 754 floating point whereas a `double` is 64bit. The only event where this isn't true is that _all three_ of the inputs and result can fit into a `float`.

Comment: I essentially wanted to know if Java was converting a*b into doubles behind the scenes. From the answer's I can see that's clearly not the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple example:

```
float a = 16777217;  // Largest int exactly representable in a float.
float b = 16777217;
System.out.println((double)(1 + a*b));

double c = 16777217;
double d = 16777217;
System.out.println(1 + c*d);
```

Output ([<kbd>Ideone</kbd>](http://ideone.com/woLyy1)):

```
2.81474976710656E14
2.8147501026509E14
```

So yes, there is a loss of precision using `float`.

Comment: To complement your answer you could add the note Peter Lawrey mentioned, that a*b is a float when a and b are floats.

Answer (score 3):

There is a loss of precision in

```
float a;
float b;
double result = 1 + a*b;
```

- the `float` representation.
- the product of `a` and `b` which will also be a `float`. Note: `a * b` is a `float`
- the addition on 1 could result in a loss of precision.

To should that `a * b` can lose more precision

```
for (int i = 1; i < 100; i += 2) {
    float a = i;
    float b = 1.0f / i;
    if ((double) a * b != a * b && a * b != 1)
        System.out.println(i + " " + (double) a * b + " " + a * b);
}
```

prints

```
41 0.999999962747097 0.99999994
47 0.9999999683350325 0.99999994
55 0.9999999683350325 0.99999994
61 0.9999999441206455 0.99999994
83 0.999999962747097 0.99999994
97 0.999999969266355 0.99999994
```

note: it could also happen recover precision lost and get the right answer after `b` has lost precision

```
for (int i = 1; i < 20; i += 2) {
    float a = i;
    float b = 1.0f / i;
    if (b != 1.0 / i && a * b == 1)
        System.out.println(i + " " + (double) a * b + " " + a * b);
}
```

prints

```
3 1.0000000298023224 1.0
5 1.0000000149011612 1.0
7 1.0000000447034836 1.0
9 1.0000000074505806 1.0
11 1.0000000298023224 1.0
13 1.000000037252903 1.0
15 1.0000000521540642 1.0
17 1.0000000037252903 1.0
19 1.0000000074505806 1.0
```

Comment: Is `float b = -1.0f/i;` represented without loss of precision?

Comment: @Quirion only if `i` is a power of 2. Otherwise there is some loss of precision which may get worse or disappear when multiplied by `i`

Comment: So your answer isn't valid as is, because you are losing precision the moment you assign  float b = -1.0f/i; , but the question stated that a and b could be represented without loss of precision. I was interested in understanding if the multiplication caused loss of precision and it does since a*b is handled as a float, as you mentioned.

Comment: @Quirion I already stated that `a*b` can lose precision or possibly happen to get back the precision you lost.

Comment: @Quirion added examples of when `a*b` can add precision or lose precision.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a loss of precision difference in a*b part when you evaluating it as floats and doubles. So yes, with some values, 2nd one will be more accurate.